# Firebase send notification with key pair value from server API

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send notification with data from the server side and display those data in activity of my choice. So far I have managed to send notification from the server and display them to any activity of my choice.

What I  do not get is

1. How to include data  in notification?
2. How receive them in an activity?

I have tried so followed guides, but I only found those send notification with data from Firebase console.

// for  server side

```
 <?php
  require "init.php";
   $message =$_POST['message'];
   $title=$_POST['title'];
 //firebase server  url
  $path_to_fcm='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  // Here is the server_key
   $server_key="#########";
  $token="#########";
   $headers= array(
     'Authorization:key='.$server_key, 
     'Content-Type:application/json'
           );
              // here use $tokens as the replace $key
$fields= array('to'=>$token,
'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message,
  'click_action'=>'com.fredycom.tundevufirebasemysql_TARGET_NOTIFICATION'
));
   $payload= json_encode($fields);
   $curl_session= curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL,$path_to_fcm);
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
   curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
       $result =curl_exec($curl_session);     
       curl_close($curl_session); 
   mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

// receive message service

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // HANDLE THE FIREBASE NOTIFICATION DATA RECEIVED  WHEN APP RUN IN THE FOREGROUND

    if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
        String title= remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String message= remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        // now we send  the data to the  main activity
        Intent intent= new Intent("com.fredycom.myreartime_FCM_MESSAGE");
        intent.putExtra("title",title);
        intent.putExtra("message",message);
        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager= LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

//  processing message in an activity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   TextView title, message;
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // REGISTER BROADCAT RECEIVER
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mHandler, new IntentFilter("com.fredycom.myreartime_FCM_MESSAGE"));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_content);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_content);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            if (key.equals("title"))
            {
                title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));
            }
            else if (key.equals("message"))
            {
                message.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));
             }
            }
           }
          }
      // HERE  IS  THE BROADICAST RECEIVER GET DATA FROM SMS RECIVING SERVICE
       private BroadcastReceiver mHandler= new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String Mytitle= intent.getStringExtra("title");
        title.setText(Mytitle);
        String Mymessage= intent.getStringExtra("message");
        message.setText(Mymessage);
        }
       };

     protected  void onPause(){
         super.onPause();
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mHandler);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PHP code, you have

```
$fields= array('to'=>$token,
'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message,
  'click_action'=>'com.fredycom.tundevufirebasemysql_TARGET_NOTIFICATION'
));
```

This would result in a payload like this:

```
{
  "to": "#######",
  "notification" : {
    "title": "title",
    "body" : "message",
    "click_action" : "com.fredycom.tundevufirebasemysql_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
  }
}
```

You are only sending a `notification`-only payload. So to answer #1, in order to add data in your notification, you should simply make use of the [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) parameter like you would do with the [`notification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) parameter. Like so:

```
$datamsg = array
(
    'key'   => 'value',
    'key2'  => 'value2',
    'key3'  => 'value3',
);
```

Then simply add it in your `$fields`:

```
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $datamsg
);
```

For #2, you already have the code to receive a `data` message, but as mentioned above, you were sending `notification`-only message, so it won't be able to *catch* anything. Just make sure you're specifying the correct key:

```
String value = remoteMessage.getData().get("key");
String value2 = remoteMessage.getData().get("key2");
String value3 = remoteMessage.getData().get("key3");
```

If you were simply hoping to get the details from the `notification` message, you should use [`RemoteMessage.getNotification()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getNotification()). Then send the data to your preferred activity. Just make sure that you understand how to handle the messages you sent, depending on the payload.

See the [Handling Messages in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) for more details.

Comment: thank you  sooo much @AL  for saving my life with this incredible explanation .. keep it up ...